# Is there a way to check when a queue from a standard library c++ is full?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

In standard c++ library, `std::queue` has no function to check when it is full.

1. Is there a way to know when it is full?
2. If not, is there a way to limit its element (like queue limit n elements)?

Comment: What do you mean with full? It grows dynamically.

Comment: A queue is never going to be full (until you run out of memory). If you want to limit the size, you have to wrap it. `if ( size() > max ) //do nothing`

Comment: It never fills up. If the system runs of physical memory to allocate space it will throw `std::bad_alloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A `std::queue` is full when its underlying container can't allocate memory to insert a new element.
2. You'll have to make that yourself, either by:

   - implementing a container capable of imposing a limit and use that in your `queue`.
   - inheriting `std::queue` and put the limit there.
   - wrapping the queue (composition) in a class that hides direct access to the queue and imposes the limit.

Here's a basic example of what implementing a container imposing the limit could look like. You'd need implement `emplace_back` etc. too for it to be really useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <queue>
#include <stdexcept>

// cheating by inheriting from std::deque
template<typename T, std::size_t max>
struct limited_deque : std::deque<T> {
    using std::deque<T>::deque;

    // the limit imposing push_back
    void push_back(const T& value) {
        if(this->size() == max) throw std::bad_alloc();
        // call the base class push_back
        std::deque<T>::push_back(value);
    }
};

// convenience alias
template<typename T, std::size_t max>
using limited_queue = std::queue<T, limited_deque<T, max>>;

int main() {
    limited_queue<int, 5> x;
    std::cout << "queue size : " << x.size() << "\n";

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) x.push(i);
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "queue size : " << x.size() << "\n";
}
```

Very probable output:

```
queue size : 0
std::bad_alloc
queue size : 5
```

Comment: I think you should not throw `std::bad_alloc`. It has a very specific meaning and if a frame further up the stack catches it, it might act wrongly on it. I guess `std::out_of_range` or something like that would be safer.

Comment: @uneven_mark True, but as a plug-and-play replacement for an existing default `std::queue`, `bad_alloc` would be caught by already existing exception handlers. If that's not the wanted behaviour, OP can customize it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::queue` container adaptor doesn’t have a member function that exports this. However, `std::queue` by default wraps a `std::deque`, which has a member function `max_size()` that returns the maximum supported size of the `deque`. If you need to use this functionality, you could switch and use `deque` rather than `queue`.

As a note, most implementations of `deque::max_size` will just return the maximum value of the integer type used to encode sizes, which likely is way larger than what you could actually fit into a `deque`. If you’re using an embedded version of C++ the library implementers might have implemented `max_size` differently, but you shouldn’t rely on this unless you have some implementation-specific documentation to that effect. Usually, `std::deque` just grows dynamically as elements are added and maxes out when no more memory is available as opposed to having a hard cap on the size.